# How to find mtu value of network through code(in python)?

Tags: python, sockets, mtu

I have to write a code where I need to send data using udp protocol in python. I need to set the packet size to the MTU value of the network. Is there any way that I can decide the MTU value of the network writing some code in python?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This answer was taken from 
http://books.google.co.il/books?id=9HGUc8AO2xQC&pg=PA31&lpg=PA31&dq#v=onepage&q&f=false
(page 31)

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
hostName = #ip here
Port = 9999
s.connect((hostName, Port))
s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, IN.IP_MTU_DISCOVER, IN.IP_PMTUDISC_DO)
try:
    s.send('#' * 1473)
except socket.error:
    print 'The message did not make it'
    option = getattr(IN, 'IP_MTU', 14)
    print 'MTU:', s.getsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, option)
else:
    print 'The big message was sent! Your network supports really big packets!'
```

Comment: Yes, It worked, but is it right to use connect in udp protocol?

Comment: @RahulKatare: Yes it is: "To get an initial estimate of the path MTU, connect a datagram socket to the destination address using connect(2) and retrieve the MTU by calling getsockopt(2) with the IP_MTU option.".

Comment: What is `IN`? `import IN` doesn't work - googling `IN` isn't easy.

Comment: Ah - `IN` defines platform specific network constants. It has been removed from Python 3.6 https://python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/whatsnew/3.6.html#api-and-feature-removals

Answer (score 2):

There is a github-gist providing this functionality:

```
import re
import socket
import struct
import logging
import subprocess
from fcntl import ioctl

SIOCGIFMTU = 0x8921
SIOCSIFMTU = 0x8922

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def get_mtu_for_address(ip):
    routeinfo = subprocess.check_output(['ip', 'route', 'get', ip])
    dev = re.search('.*dev (\w+) .*', routeinfo).groups()[0]
    mtuinfo = subprocess.check_output(['ip', 'link', 'show', dev])
    mtu = re.search('.*mtu ([0-9]+) .*', mtuinfo).groups()[0]
    return int(mtu)

class Iface:
    def __init__(self, ifname):
        self.ifname = ifname

    def get_mtu(self):
        '''Use socket ioctl call to get MTU size'''
        s = socket.socket(type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        ifr = self.ifname + '\x00'*(32-len(self.ifname))
        try:
            ifs = ioctl(s, SIOCGIFMTU, ifr)
            mtu = struct.unpack('<H',ifs[16:18])[0]
        except Exception, s:
            log.critical('socket ioctl call failed: {0}'.format(s))
            raise

        log.debug('get_mtu: mtu of {0} = {1}'.format(self.ifname, mtu))
        self.mtu = mtu
        return mtu

    def set_mtu(self, mtu):
        '''Use socket ioctl call to set MTU size'''
        s = socket.socket(type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        ifr = struct.pack('<16sH', self.ifname, mtu) + '\x00'*14
        try:
            ifs = ioctl(s, SIOCSIFMTU, ifr)
            self.mtu = struct.unpack('<H',ifs[16:18])[0]
        except Exception, s:
            log.critical('socket ioctl call failed: {0}'.format(s))
            raise

        log.debug('set_mtu: mtu of {0} = {1}'.format(self.ifname, self.mtu))

        return self.mtu


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    logging.basicConfig()

    mtu = None
    if len(sys.argv) > 2:
        dev,mtu = sys.argv[1:]
    elif len(sys.argv) > 1:
        dev = sys.argv[1]
    else:
        dev = 'eth0'

    iface = Iface(dev)
    if mtu is not None:
        iface.set_mtu(int(mtu))

    print dev,'mtu =',iface.get_mtu()
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/nzjrs/8934855

Comment: Does not work for me in Python 3.7. The `ioctl` call in `get_mtu` raises: `OSError: [Errno 6] Device not configured`

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer did not work for me in Python 3.7. I get: `OSError: [Errno 6] Device not configured`

But, `psutil` now has this built in.

```py
import psutil
print(psutil.net_if_stats())
```

Results in:

```
{
  'lo0': snicstats(isup=True, duplex=<NicDuplex.NIC_DUPLEX_UNKNOWN: 0>, speed=0, mtu=16384), 
  'en0': snicstats(isup=True, duplex=<NicDuplex.NIC_DUPLEX_UNKNOWN: 0>, speed=0, mtu=1500), 
  ...
}
```

Comment: this gives you the MTU of your network interface. not the whole packet routing path.

Comment: @AminPial Correct. After this I call to ping, setting the packet size (minus TCP header size) to check the path all the way can handle it.

Comment: yap, right. ping with ```DF (Don't Fragment)``` flag and check the min MTU. Anyway, how would you approach to mind min MSS (MTU- IP- Transport) via ping? brute force? or a binary search? or any other way?

Comment: @AminPial I read somewhere it was 28 bytes and then tested it once by manual binary search. I use `-c 1 -M do -s <mtu - 28>`. You mention the DF flag. How can that be set?

Comment: I haved tested in windows (linux or mac's ping might have different flags). You can read my answer below. ```-f -l {size}``` -f is for DF flag.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do a binary search over ping with `DF (Don't Fragment)` flag. Here is a working coding to find MTU through the above-mentioned technique. It gives you `minimum MTU of the full packet routing path AKA the max payload you can send.

**Tested only on Windows (won't work on Linux/Mac as ping flags are different in different OS)**

```py
# tested on Windows 10 Home and python 3.6 [at Great Istanbul, Turkey]
import subprocess
from time import perf_counter


class FindMinMtu:
    """
        - Find Minimum "Maximum Transmission Unit" of a packet routing path via Binary Search

        - Suppose you want to find how much data you can send in each packet
          from London to Turkey?
        - Now we need to remember MTU and MSS (Max. Segment size) isn't not the same.
          MSS is the actual data (not headers) you can send. A typical formula for MSS is
          MSS = MTU - (IP header_size  + TCP/UDP/Any Transport Layer Protocol header_size)
          whereas MTU = Everything in packet - Ethernet headers
          MTU typical refers to Ethernet MTU, AKA how much payload can an ethernet cable push through next hop.
    """

    def __init__(self, url: str):
        self.url = url

        self._low_mtu = 500
        # typically ethernet cables can carry 1500 bytes (but Jumbo fiber can carry upto 9K bytes AFAIK)
        # so increase it as per your requirements
        self._high_mtu = 1500
        self._last_accepted = self._low_mtu

    @staticmethod
    def yield_console_output(command):
        p = subprocess.Popen(command,
                             stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                             stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        return iter(p.stdout.readline, b'')

    def does_accept_mtu_size(self, size) -> bool:
        command = 'ping {domain_name} -t -f -l {size}'.format(domain_name=self.url,
                                                           size=size).split()
        for line in self.yield_console_output(command):
            line = line.decode(encoding='utf-8')
            if line.startswith('Packet') and 'DF' in line:
                return False
            elif line.startswith('Reply'):
                return True

    def find_min_mtu(self):
        while self._low_mtu <= self._high_mtu:
            if not (self.does_accept_mtu_size(self._low_mtu), self.does_accept_mtu_size(self._high_mtu)):
                return self._last_accepted
            else:
                middle = (self._high_mtu + self._low_mtu) // 2
                print("Low: {} High: {} Middle: {}".format(self._low_mtu, self._high_mtu, middle))
                if self.does_accept_mtu_size(middle):
                    self._last_accepted = middle
                    self._low_mtu = middle + 1
                else:
                    self._high_mtu = middle - 1
        return self._last_accepted


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = perf_counter()
    # please provide protocol less domain name (without http://, https:// and also without www or any subdomain)
    # provide the naked url (without www/subdomain)
    f = FindMinMtu("libwired.com")
    print("\nMTU: {} bytes (Found in {} seconds)".format(f.find_min_mtu(), perf_counter() - start))
```